Laravel Cached Config Values are not available on next request
I am facing a very strange issue in Laravel 11.
I change the file dynamically via a form and then call Artisan::call('config:cache'); and then redirect the user to dashboard page.
The problem is that we don't see the new values, but the previous ones.
But if we put PHP sleep(3) and then redirect, we see the new values.
The question is the Artisan::call('config:cache') call not synchronous?
I know that laravel load all configs at boot time. Why new config cached file is not immediately accessible then?
It seems that the new bootstrap/cache/config.php file is not immediately accessible, only after 2-3 seconds.
Τhe code is something like this: This is not reflecting new changes to dashboard page.
DotenvEditor::setKey('SITE_NAME', $request->input('site_name'));
Artisan::call('config:cache');

return redirect('/home/dashboard');

It works as expected If we put a small delay before the redirect.
DotenvEditor::setKey('SITE_NAME', $request->input('site_name'));
Artisan::call('config:cache');
sleep(3);

return redirect('/home/dashboard');


if you're changing the config, it wouldn't make sense to alter the env variable. did you try changing the config itself using config('config-key', 'value');?
